# React: change modal's content without passing entire DOM elements as a props?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, reactstrap

I am new to React and currently I am trying to build a Two-Fact-Auth Modal-like UI in my project.

The Modal looks relatively sample as well.

1. Title
2. A message
3. Modal Content(which can be a inputbox, or one or more drop-down selections, or just displaying string)
4. A Button

Imagine there are some modals: First one ask you to enter your phone number. After you typed your phone number, it get direct to second modal and second modal will display the phone number you typed and ask you to confirm, and third modal will display other things and so on.

My approach to this is to build a my own modal component using `ReactStrap`.

```
export default class ModalControl extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <Modal isOpen={this.props.isOpen}>
                    <ModalHeader >{this.props.title}</ModalHeader>
                    <ModalBody>
                        <p>{this.props.message}</p>
                        <p>{"Content that is change dynamically"}</p>
                    </ModalBody>
                    <ModalFooter>
                        <Button color="info" onClick={() => this.props.clickAction>{this.props.buttonLabel}</Button>
                    </ModalFooter>
                </Modal>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

However, One of the problem I have is to change the modal content. Since the Modal does not know if itself contains a `selection`, `'A input box'`, or '`Just a string`', what should i do so the ModalControl can take content that is dynamically changing?

**My attempt:** 
I tried to pass entire DOM elements as a string to modal and parse it in the modalControl. However, I have read a SO post that saying passing Dom Elements is not recommended in React.

In my main, i have something like this, but apparently it is not rendering

```
<ModalControl
    isOpen={true}
    title={"Code Authentication"}
    message={"For your security, we need to verify your identity by sending a code to your phone number"}
    buttonLabel={"Verify Code"}
>
<div className="row">
          <div className="col-sm-6">
              {this.getPhoneList()}
          </div>
          <div className="col-sm-6">
              {this.getMethodList()}
          </div>
</div>
</ModalControl>
```

`What i want to achieve`: How do I implement a modal class whose modal content that is dynamically changing? Since I am new to React, I am not sure if this is the best practice. If it is not, is there a better approach?

Comment: *"...but apparently it is not rendering..."* Do you use `props.children`? That's how the children get passed to you. The documentation doesn't (in my view) make that clear enough, but [this page](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html) and [this page](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#children-in-jsx) describe it.

Comment: Using `this.props.children` is one approach.

Comment: @DarrenSweeney what will be the best approach then?

Comment: @aDev It sounds like you want to have each input on it's own modal then the next modal confirms, why not just have it on one? Cut down the clicks and time wasted. Then confirm on one... Up to you at the end of the day and this question is not about UI/UX so your call

Comment: @DarrenSweeney if I have one modal that do everything. Then I would have to change entire modal's content. Then it means that i have to safe all my content in a state, which I think will make my code looks messy and I don't know how would I do that on top of my head. However, since I am new to React, so I can be completely wrong. I will keep your opinion in mind.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks, it worked like I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You have to maintain a state which holds variables that can dynamically change.

First you set the state.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    variableX: "default string"
  };
}
```

You can then use React's setState() method to update the state

```
this.setState({
  variableX: "updated string"
});
```

In your render method you can then access the variable

```
render() {
 const { variableX } = this.state;     

 return (
  <div>{variableX}</div>
 );
}
```

You can also pass the state as a prop to child components

```
// Parent component
render() {
 const { variableX } = this.state;     

 return (
  <div>
   <ChildComponent variableX={variableX} />
  </div>
 );
}

// Child component
render() {
 const { variableX } = this.props;     

 return (
  <div>
   {variableX}
  </div>
 );
}
```

One thing to note is that you never want to mutate the state. You can search many articles regarding this using the terms "react state immutability"
You should read: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html
In a large application where it's more difficult to maintain a state, and where you don't want to keep passing properties all the time, you can consider using Redux with React:
https://redux.js.org/basics/usagewithreact